# State space representation in s-domain

Tags: linear-systems, state-space

I was supposed to find state space representation and its matrices of this system:

[image: system in s-domain]

and I have no idea, how to do this. We were told not to transfer the system to time domain, but I can only do state space representation from time domain schemas.

When I tried to solve this, I got matrices
$$A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc@{\ }r}
    -a & k  \\
    -b & -p \\
    \end{array} \right)$$

$$B =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc@{\ }r}
    0  \\
    b \\
    \end{array} \right)$$

$$C =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc@{\ }r}
    1 & 0  \\
    \end{array} \right)$$

$$D =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc@{\ }r}
    0
    \end{array} \right)$$

Is that right? If not, how sould I solve it?

Comment: You should define what the matrices $A, B, C, D$ refer to in your state-space model. Then it should be pretty easy to tell if you're right.

Comment: I thought it is globaly used. Exactly what matrices at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_representation means.

Comment: Would it help if you knew that the transfer function of a system described by $[A,B,C,D]$ is $C(s{\bf I} - A)^{-1}B + D$ ?

Comment: No, that would not help. I would prefer if enybody could tell, how to solve it. Cause I don't understand it.

Comment: You say `I have no idea, how to do this` and yet you present an answer.  Can you detail how you got your answer, and what you don't understand about it?

Comment: I went like:
$$X_2(s) = (U(s)-X_1(s)) \cdot \frac {b}{s+p} $$
$$X_1(s) = X_2(s) \cdot \frac {k}{s+a}$$

That could mean:
$$sX_2(s) + pX_2(s) = bU(s) - bX_1(s) \to \dot x_2(t) = bu(t) - bx_1(t) - px_2(t)$$
$$sX_1(s) + aX_1(s) = kX_2(s) \to \dot x_1(t) = -ax_1(t) + kx_2(t)$$

and output sould be: 
$$y(t) = x_1(t)$$

that would lead to matrices I wrote. But I don't know, if I can do that this way, or if that is what was the task, cause we were told not to transfer to time domain, but I can't imagine how to do it without transfer I did.

Answer (score 1):

From visual inspection of the given block diagram, we obtain

$$\begin{bmatrix} s+a & -k\\ b & s+p\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_1 (s)\\ X_2 (s) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ b\end{bmatrix} U (s)$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\left( s \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} -a & k\\ -b & -p\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} X_1 (s)\\ X_2 (s) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ b\end{bmatrix} U (s)$$

Hence,

$$\mathrm A := \begin{bmatrix} -a & k\\ -b & -p\end{bmatrix} \qquad\qquad \mathrm b := \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ b\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $Y (s) = X_1 (s)$,

$$\mathrm c^\top := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad\qquad d := 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$L(s)$ being the loop gain, the closed loop is given by $P(s) = L(s)/(1+L(s)$ hence this gives

$$
\begin{align*}
P(s) &= \frac{bk}{(s+a)(s+p)+bk} = \frac{bk}{(s+a)(s+p)+bk}\frac{X(s)}{X(s)}\\
&=\frac{bk}{s^2 + (a+p)s + (ap + bk)}\frac{X(s)}{X(s)}\\
\end{align*}
$$
Then if you write out the state equations

$$
P(s) = \left[\begin{array}{cc|c}0&1&0\\-(ap+bk)&-(a+p)&b\\\hline k&0&0\end{array}\right]
$$